# Resize template or page size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, template

I'm trying to find a way to print a map I've made on 2 different page sizes while keeping it to scale on both.

Originally I've made the map to the ARCH E page size. - print and its to scale.

Then if I save that as a template and create new layout with ARCH D page size, import the previous template it opens it up at the original (ARCH E) size and I'm unable to resize the whole template together without it disorganizing all of my items.

Is there a better way to resize everything to fit onto a different page size?

Comment: I'm not aware of an easier way of doing it, but it might help to select multiple items and resize them at one go to fit the new page size. You will still need to manually change the spacing, font sizes etc. - If you have lots of text boxes, consider saving a "base" font size as a layout variable, with all the text items using that variable or a multiple thereof for font sizes. That way you just change the variable and all the text boxes update. See links in this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/455605/98784

Comment: not quite what you're looking for, but if you save the E-sized map to a pdf, you can open that in most PDF viewers and print it to a D-sized sheet, with "scale to fit".

Comment: @Llaves but then the map content will not be in the numeric scale printed on the map. - we created templates for all common page sizes and drag & drop those into our projects if needed.

Comment: @eric- it's not clear the OP said they were printing a numeric scale on the map. Using a scale bar eliminates that problem.

Comment: Ultimately  i need the printed maps to be useable for navigation. So I need to be able to use a scale ruler on the map. If i just choose a "scale to fit" option in the printer settings, yes the scale bar is still accurate but the actual map grid spacing will not align with a ruler.